# CTL port in a motor controller

Tags: motor

When I look at my [160A motor controller](http://www.ampflow.com/motor_controller.htm), it has a port that is called "CTL."
What does CTL stand for? Is that a sort of protocol like RS232?

Comment: Who makes this controller?  What is the model?  Do you have a photo?  Did you look at the manufacturers web site?

Comment: Yes, Non of the information is online. And like I wrote, I have the 160A motor controller. It's sold by ampflow. My rank does not allow me to post pictures yet. But here is the link:
http://www.ampflow.com/motor_controller.htm

Comment: The pictures on the website are too small to read the writing on the motor controller.  Can you take a better picture and post it?

Comment: My rank does not allow me to post pictures yet, but I'll try to use a dropbox link or something.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask the vendor?  At any rate, what type of connector is this?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's unclear what you're asking. It's also an electronics question not strictly about robotics. You may be better off re-asking at the electronics SE and linking a datasheet. I don't even see a CTL in the page linked.

Comment: no, dont close it. it helps others

Answer (score 2):

From that page,

> This speed adjuster plugs into the radio control inputs of the motor controllers.

So my guess would be that CTL is short for "Control".  Without a better picture or a user manual, only the vendor would be able to say for sure.

Comment: I solved the problem